# Compare an array within an object with an array within another object - both objects within the same parent array

Tags: arrays, loops, object

I have an array of objects (~12 000 objects) each object looks like:

`{id: num, name: "first last", identifiers: [num, num, num, num]}`

What I need to do is compare each object with each other object within the array and if two objects have a matching identifier, I need to create another object in a completely separate array linking the two object ids.

When each object only had one number as an identifier, I could do it quite easily with:

```
 let data = [*arr with objects*];
 let nodes = data;
 let len = nodes.length;
 let links = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    let arrTest = nodes.findIndex((e) => e.identifiers === data[i].identifiers);
     if (arrTest !== -1) {
       const newLink = new Object();
       newLink.source = nodes[arrTest].id;
       newLink.target = data[i].id;
       links.push(newLink);
      }
   }
```

However, with identifiers now being arrays I'm lost on the logic to receive the same outcome. What seems to make it harder for some attempts I've made is that some objects still only have a single number as an identifier - throwing errors if array methods such as .length are used??

My only thought right now is to create a new array with each identifier as a separate object with the id it originated from such as:
`{identifier: num, id: num}`
from this, it would just be a case of iterating through that array and connecting and creating new links through a similar method as above.

Wanted to know if there was a more efficient method, my JS is fairly limited and just really started making apps with it.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could check the type of the identifier by doing something like-

```
if (typeof identifier === "number") {
    // do what you are already doing
} else {
    // it's an array so you can loop here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary to quickly access all other (previous) items with the same identifier

```js
let data = [* arr with objects *];
const itemsByIdentifiers = {};

let links = [];
for (let item of data) {
  // get (or create) the list with the recorded items for this identifier
  let others = itemsByIdentifiers[item.identifiers] ||= [];
  // iterate over that list and add the links
  for (let other of others) {
    links.push({
      source: other.id,
      target: item.id
    });
  }
  // add myself to the list, so future items can find me and link to me
  others.push(item);
}
```